# How store keys and values of dictionary to different field in django

Tags: python, django

i have written a code to get details of city and thier ids.which is in a dictionary form.
now i split it in keys and values so that i can store keys to id field and values in city field.
i am facing problem when doing it
here is my code

models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    cityid=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        r=requests.get('http://lab.iamrohit.in/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php?type=getCities&stateId=5')

        resp = requests.get(
            'http://lab.iamrohit.in/php_ajax_country_state_city_dropdown/api.php?type=getCities&stateId=1'
        )

        cities_dict = resp.json()['result']
        id1=list(cities_dict.keys())
        id2=list(cities_dict.values())

        for i in id1:
            obj1=City.objects.create()
            obj1.cityid=i

            for j in id2:
               obj1.cityid=j
            obj1.save()
        return HttpResponse (json.dumps(cities_dict))
```

i know that there is blunder in my views.py please help me
thanks in advance

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: please show `resp.json()`

Comment: i want to save keys value in stateid and values in state.and this is not happen this is my problem

Comment: Why do you repeatedly set `obj1.cityid` to different values? It's an IntegerField, it can only have one single value.

Comment: how can i write my new code

Comment: what your code does is, creates a city object assigns the last cityid from json to it and save it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save id and city you should be doing something like this:

```
cities_dict = resp.json()['result']
for id in cities_dict:
    obj1=City.objects.create(cityid=id, city=cities_dict[id])
    obj1.save()
```

Comment: why my entris save as (id) 4,2,3,1 instead of 1,2,3,4

Comment: because dicts are not ordered

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use dict.items to get the key AND the value in one shot:

```
cities_dict = resp.json()['result']
for k, v in cities_dict.items():
    obj1 = City.objects.create(cityid=k, city=v)
    obj1.save()
```